# question about crash report

Tags: crash, ibus

This morning I received a crash report on Ubuntu 20.04 startup. Generally I look at these reports to see if maybe I'm doing something wrong (software which hasn't been updated etc.) This one is on IBus Preferences which I admit that I know nothing about (so I never knowingly set any preferences).

What caught my eye was the Installation Media as Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.... What is an installation media object from 18.04 doing on my 20.04 machine? Does this look right? If not, what is the proper way to fix it?

I'll send the crash report, but if there is something I need to fix, then I should do it.

Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: I would read that as your system was installed from a 18.04.2 ISO, then *release-upgraded* in the past to your current 20.04 system. The box I'm writing this comment on will report a 17.10 installation that's been *release-upgraded* many times and is now running 20.10 (ie. development release, I upgrade every 6 months staying on the *development* cycle)

Comment: So there seems nothing "wrong" with my system which could have caused the crash? I did indeed upgrade from 18.04LTS. Whether I did a fresh install at 18.04 or upgraded from something else, I no longer remember. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I have no details about your crash, so cannot comment on it. Clean installs tend to have less problems (esp. when compared to constantly *release-upgraded* systems such as my own now having had 6 bumps of release since I installed. Slight differences exist on upgraded systems (conf files were setup by older versions of software for example) but these differences are usually minor.  Detail is kept for bug *triagers* & *developers* so they can detect a pattern that maybe useful in finding and thus fixing any issues discovered.

Answer (score 1):

I would read that as your system was installed from a 18.04.2 ISO, then *release-upgraded* in the past to your current 20.04 system. The box I'm writing this comment on will report a 17.10 installation that's been release-upgraded many times and is now running 20.10 (ie. development release, I upgrade every 6 months staying on the *development* cycle)

I have no details about your crash, so cannot comment on it. Clean installs tend to have less problems (esp. when compared to constantly *release-upgraded* systems such as my own now having had 6 bumps of release since I installed. Slight differences exist on upgraded systems (conf files were setup by older versions of software for example) but these differences are usually minor.

Detail (*of installation media, when, upgraded etc*) is kept for bug *triagers* & *developers* so they can detect a pattern that maybe useful in finding and thus fixing any issues discovered.

Comment: I would try a fresh install if I thought it worth the effort. I don't get a lot of crashes, and most of them come from Nautilus. This is the first time ibus has come up. My desire is not to give a bug report if I haven't done all that I can on my end. For example I discovered that sudo apt autoremove can print how many programs have not been upgraded. It isn't fair for me to bother the people who are trying to service the problem if I haven't bothered to update everything which might need to be updated - I am just wasting their time. This was my reason for asking the question.